# Cannot find the memory leak. Staring for 1 hour

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

Following C code has memory leak. I'm staring it for one hour but can't find it. I've been able to narrow it down to that function but still no luck for improvement.

Can you help me to find it?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
void insert ( LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value[SIZE] ) {
    LISTNODEPTR newPtr, previousPtr, currentPtr;
    int cmp;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));

    if ( newPtr != NULL ) {

        newPtr->data = malloc(sizeof(SIZE));

        strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        /* Comparision to detect & remove duplicates nodes */
        while ( currentPtr != NULL ) {
            cmp = strcmp(value, currentPtr->data);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                /* you're at the point where you need to add the node */
                break;
            } else if (cmp == 0) {
                /* value is equal, no duplicate is allowed, leave */

                // since it is not added, destroy!
                free(newPtr->data);
                free(newPtr);

                return;
            }

            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

            if ( previousPtr == NULL ) {
                newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
                *sPtr = newPtr;
            }
            else{
                previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
                newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
            }

    }


}
```

**Edit:**

More of the code:

```
#define SIZE 1001

struct listNode {
    char *data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode LISTNODE;
typedef LISTNODE *LISTNODEPTR;

/* Function prototype */
void insert ( LISTNODEPTR *, char[SIZE] );
```

Valgrind:

```
==19906== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19906==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 3 blocks
==19906==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19906==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19906==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19906==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

If I turn sizeof(SIZE) to SIZE, then memory leaks become +3000.

**Edit 2:**

I do deallocate them in main()

```
while ( startPtr != NULL ){
    LISTNODEPTR tmp = startPtr;
    startPtr = startPtr->nextPtr;
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak? and `malloc(sizeof(SIZE));` are you sure?

Comment: What is `SIZE` here ?? `newPtr->data = malloc(sizeof(SIZE));`

Comment: pretty sure that's supposed to be **`malloc(SIZE)`**. Your current `malloc(sizeof(SIZE))` would malloc the size of an `int` if it is a macro (and I've no reason to think it isn't). So unless the strings you're copying are 3-chars long or shorter on a 32-bit `int` implementation, you're invoking undefined behavior with that `strcpy`.

Comment: You did not check the return code of the second `malloc`.

Comment: typedeffing pointers considered harmful ...

Comment: Btw, props for using Valgrind.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in this function? That's where the memory gets allocated, but maybe you should look at where it should be freed.

Comment: newPtr = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODE)) should be newPtr = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODEPTR)) ?

Comment: @Vagish I don't think so, that is one of the things that are correct.

Comment: `else if (cmp == 0)` you don't seem to `free(newPtr)` if this condition is not satisfied in the `while` loop. Just one I saw, there might be others.

Comment: @WhozCraig When I make it `malloc(SIZE)`, `definitely lost: 3,003 bytes in 3 blocks`

Comment: I don't care about the increased size loss. The previous code was flat-wrong and needed to be fixed. Your actual leak is from your failure to release the data block before the node pointer in your free. Finally, you don't need all the additional pointer juggling when doing this. That pointer-to-pointer passed to your function can do almost all of this easily. [see example](http://pastebin.com/EVHvauLq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You free the nodes, but not the data.

```
while ( startPtr != NULL ){
    LISTNODEPTR tmp = startPtr;
    startPtr = startPtr->nextPtr;
    free(tmp->data);     // Line added
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: I guess this was added after I posted my answer!

Comment: Fudge me! Sorry about that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a memory leak because the pointers you allocate locally in the function are never accessible from outside the function.

Also `malloc(sizeof(SIZE))` is wrong, you should change it to `malloc(SIZE)`, and if it's a fixed value, you should proably declare the `data` member as `char data[SIZE]` instead of `malloc()`ing space for it.

**SHORT ANSWER**

The memory leak is due to your program not `free()`ing the `malloc()`ed memory.

Comment: When I make it `malloc(SIZE)`, `definitely lost: 3,003 bytes in 3 blocks`

Comment: as said above, `free` your `malloc`-ed space after use.

Comment: @user4220128 using valgrind is a really good thing, but it seems that you need to learn how `malloc()`/`free()` work.

Comment: @user4220128: Since you seem to be using Valgrind anyway: When you use `--leak-check=full`, Valgrind will tell you where the `malloc`s without matching `free`s occur.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified:

- changed the `value[SIZE]` argument to a `char*`, since that is what it is
- without the confusing (and invisible) typedef
- malloc() is only called once you **know** you really need the new node
- removed excessive variables and conditions caused by *not using the pointer to pointer construct*
- used strdup(), because that is simpler

---

```
struct listnode {
        struct listnode *nextPtr;
        char *data;
        };

void insert ( struct listnode **pp, char *value ) {
    struct listnode *newPtr;
    int cmp;

        /* find place to insert in LL */
    while ( *pp) {
        /* Comparision to detect & remove duplicates nodes */
            cmp = strcmp(value, (*pp)->data);
                /* Duplicate: nothing to do ... */
            if (cmp == 0) return;
                /* you're at the point where you need to add the node */
            if (cmp < 0) break;
            pp = &(*pp)->nextPtr;
            }

    /* when you get here, *pp points to the pointer you want to change.
    ** *pp could even be NULL (if we are at the end of the list)
    */

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);    
    if ( !newPtr ) { barf(); return; }

    newPtr->data = strdup (value);
        /* you could check newPtr->data here, and if null: free(newPtr) */

        /* "steal" the pointer */
    newPtr->nextPtr = *pp;
        /* and inject the new pointer into the LL */
    *pp = newPtr;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the code based on your help. I'm stuck again, if you could help me out that would be much appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461513/to-allocate-or-not-to-allocate-invalid-read-of-size-1-errors-staring-for-2-ho