# To allocate or not to allocate. Invalid read of size 1 errors. [Staring for 2 hours]

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

This is the code I'm working on

```
code
```

However there are problems. Some or all might be because of not allocating space for `data` in nodes (line 135~) because the `line` is changing during iteration in `main`. But when I allocate space for it, at line 135, the outcome doesn't change much and there is memory leak. I'm stuck.

I'm about to go crazy. Can you help me to fix errors?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Output:

```
a@ubuntu:~/os/hw1$ ./o f1.txt f2.txt o.txt
*** Error in `./o': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001e8b250 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Valgrind:

```
a@ubuntu:~/os/hw1$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./o f1.txt f2.txt o.txt
==21643== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21643== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21643== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21643== Command: ./o f1.txt f2.txt o.txt
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid write of size 2
==21643==    at 0x4C2F843: __GI_memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:917)
==21643==    by 0x4EA5ED7: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:115)
==21643==    by 0x400959: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid write of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4EA5FD4: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:122)
==21643==    by 0x400959: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c2 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4EC28BC: strtok (strtok.S:137)
==21643==    by 0x40092F: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4EC28EC: strtok (strtok.S:163)
==21643==    by 0x40092F: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4EC28F3: strtok (strtok.S:167)
==21643==    by 0x40092F: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid write of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4EC2919: strtok (strtok.S:186)
==21643==    by 0x40092F: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4C2EC31: strcmp (vg_replace_strmem.c:755)
==21643==    by 0x400A67: insert (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==    by 0x400942: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4C2DB62: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:412)
==21643==    by 0x4EBF66D: strdup (strdup.c:41)
==21643==    by 0x400ABB: insert (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==    by 0x400942: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4C2DB74: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:412)
==21643==    by 0x4EBF66D: strdup (strdup.c:41)
==21643==    by 0x400ABB: insert (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==    by 0x400942: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 2
==21643==    at 0x4C2F840: __GI_memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:917)
==21643==    by 0x400ABB: insert (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==    by 0x400942: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid read of size 1
==21643==    at 0x4C2EC48: strcmp (vg_replace_strmem.c:755)
==21643==    by 0x400A67: insert (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==    by 0x400942: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x400985: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643==  Address 0x51fc2c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==21643==    at 0x4C2BCD7: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==21643==    by 0x4008F6: main (in /home/a/os/hw1/o)
==21643== 
==21643== 
==21643== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21643==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21643==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 11 frees, 1,878 bytes allocated
==21643== 
==21643== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21643== 
==21643== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21643== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `if(newPtr->data == NULL)  free(newPtr);` and you dereference the `free()`d pointer immediaetly after that. You must return from the function after freeing.

Comment: seriously? `strtok(line, "\n");`, just `if (line[read - 1] == '\n') line[--read] = '\0';` would be fine and more explicit. Don't take it the wrong way, I think you are going to be a great programmer.

Comment: @iharob: I didn't read through the code to find the context, but your 3rd point has different semantics --- it copies the value into whatever `ptr` was previous pointing at (instead of just changing `ptr`).

Comment: @TimČas absolutely right, i am deleting the comment.

Comment: First there was a link to the code; then there was the code; now there is neither. So what are we debugging here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you free `line` the first time you should set it to `NULL` and `len` to `0`

```
if (line)
    free(line);
line = NULL; /* make it NULL so you can call getline() again or just don't free it yet */
len  = 0;
```

other wise subsequent calls to `getline()` will try to access the invalid pointer.

Also, as I commented

```
if(newPtr->data == NULL)
    free(newPtr);
```

is wrong because you will dereference `newPtr` anyway, so you must

```
if (newPtr->data == NULL)
{
    free(newPtr);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Good catch - and set `len = 0` too.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't remember if that is required, let me check the manual.

Comment: @WeatherVane it wouldn't be bad but the manual says that if the first argument is `NULL` then `*n`  value will be ignored.

Comment: Sorry where I looked it said both!

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok ill add it then.

Comment: Upvoted anyway for a good catch. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: @WeatherVane my local manpage says `If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program.  (In  this  case,  the  value  in  *n  is
       ignored.)` And I copied that text from the page displayed in my konsole window.

Comment: I think I need to update my manpages package, I use a custom linux which has my own package manager, so I need to check for updates manually for now.

Answer (score 1):

On line 138, if the condition is false (could not allocate space for string) then you forget to return, i.e.:

```
if(newPtr->data == NULL) {
    free(newPtr);
    return;
}
```

This, if it happens, will surely cause memory problems. There may be other problems (still searching...)

Comment: @WeatherVane Because the original code was at a link and I copied it formatted it and pasted it here.